# hook ajax requests by using webkit

Tags: python, ajax, webkit

for example:
how could I get "ajax_link.php?id=1&t=xxxx" this link and its url, forms below by using webkit?

```
<script>
if(window.ActiveXObject) ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
else ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('post',"ajax_link.php?id=1&amp;t="+Math.random(),false);
ajax.send();
document.write("ajax.ResponseText length:"+ajax.responseText.length);
</script>
```